# JAXB - trying to use an enumeration within an "xsd:any" tag

Tags: java, jaxb

I will say right off the bat that I don’t doubt for a nanosecond that my problem here is self-inflicted, but I’ve made a run at fixing it myself from about every angle I can think of and I’m still completely stumped – any help would be much appreciated!

What I’m trying to accomplish is not rocket science – I have been given a schema that I’m calling "Provided" to denote that this has been provided to me by a 3rd party (i.e. I cannot change/edit it).  Note that this schema contains an xsd:any tag that serves as a place to put user defined data.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://somecompany.com/schema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://somecompany.com/schema">

<xsd:element name="Parent">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="UserDefinedArea" type="UserDefinedAreaType"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="UserDefinedAreaType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Using XJC to generate code for this schema is simple enough.  XJC produces a class for the UserDefinedAreaType which gives me a List to stuff with user defined data.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "UserDefinedAreaType", propOrder = {
"any"
})
public class UserDefinedAreaType {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> any;
}
```

One of the things I’d like to stuff into this UserDefinedArea is an enum (to give some extra validation/type safety assurance).  Creating a schema to represent this is also easy enough.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://mycompany.com/schema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://mycompany.com/schema">

<xsd:simpleType name="MyEnum">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="active"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="inactive"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>
```

XJC happily creates a class for this schema.

```
@XmlType(name = "MyEnum", namespace = "http://mycompany.com/schema")
@XmlEnum
public enum MyEnum {

    @XmlEnumValue("active")
    ACTIVE("active"),
    @XmlEnumValue("inactive")
    INACTIVE("inactive");
    private final String value;
}
```

Now some simple code to test drive this.

```
private static final ObjectFactory of = new ObjectFactory();

private static final JAXBContext jc;

static {
    try {
        jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class);
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
       throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parent parent = new Parent();
    UserDefinedAreaType udat = new UserDefinedAreaType();
    parent.setUserDefinedArea(udat);

    MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.ACTIVE;
    udat.getAny().add(myEnum);

    File file = new File("output.txt");
    try {
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.marshal(parent, file);
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is what I’m hoping to get.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Parent xmlns:ns2="http://somecompany.com/schema" xlmns:ns3="http://mycompany.com/schema">
<UserDefinedArea>
    <ns3:MyEnum>active</ns3:MyEnum>
</UserDefinedArea>
</ns2:Parent>
```

But this is what I actually get.

```
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class com.mycompany.schema.MyEnum nor any of its super class is known to this context.
```

The obvious thing to do would be to add MyEnum.class to the JAXBContext (i.e. “jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class, MyEnum.class);”), but all that nets me is:

```
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "com.mycompany.schema.MyEnum" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
```

The next obvious thing to do is to make MyEnum (and anything else I plan to stuff into this UserArea) an @XmlRootElement, but I have had zero success actually making this happen!  I’m either missing an obvious way to create MyEnum as an @XmlRootElement OR there is something fundamentally flawed with my approach (i.e. I’m approaching this problem from the wrong direction).

Many thanks in advance for any ideas anyone might have.

Answer (score 0):

Solution one -

Schema change:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://mycompany.com/schema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://mycompany.com/schema">
    <xsd:element name="MyEnum" type="MyEnumType"/>
    <xsd:simpleType name="MyEnumType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
             <xsd:enumeration value="active"/>
             <xsd:enumeration value="inactive"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Which creates a class for "MyEnumType":

```
@XmlType(name = "MyEnumType", namespace = "http://mycompany.com/schema")
@XmlEnum
public enum MyEnumType {

    @XmlEnumValue("active")
    ACTIVE("active"),
    @XmlEnumValue("inactive")
    INACTIVE("inactive");
    private final String value;
}
```

And also a useful ObjectFactory method for creating "MyEnums" (of type "MyEnumType"):

```
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://mycompany.com/schema", name = "MyEnum")
public JAXBElement<MyEnumType> createMyEnum(MyEnumType value) {
    return new JAXBElement<MyEnumType>(_MyEnum_QNAME, MyEnumType.class, null, value);
}
```

Full test drive code:

```
private static final ObjectFactory of = new ObjectFactory();

private static final JAXBContext jc;

static {
    try {
        jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class, MyEnumType.class);
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Parent parent = new Parent();
    UserDefinedAreaType udat = new UserDefinedAreaType();
    parent.setUserDefinedArea(udat);

    JAXBElement<MyEnumType> goodEnum = of.createMyEnum(MyEnumType.fromValue("active"));
    udat.getAny().add(goodEnum);

    File file = new File("output.txt");

    try {
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.marshal(parent, file);
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Produces desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Parent xmlns:ns2="http://somecompany.com/schema">
    <UserDefinedArea>
        <ns3:MyEnum xmlns:ns3="http://mycompany.com/schema">active</ns3:MyEnum>
    </UserDefinedArea>
</ns2:Parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

An `xsd:any` is a container for any *element*, but your schema hasn't declared any elements, only a `MyEnum` *type*.  If you write your additional schema to delcare `MyEnum` as a top-level element with an anonymous type instead of as a top-level type

```
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://mycompany.com/schema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://mycompany.com/schema">

<xsd:element name="MyEnum">
  <xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="active"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="inactive"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>
```

then you should get the `@XmlRootElement` annotation you need.

Comment: I actually tried this approach earlier - wrapping the simpleType in an element ends up not creating a type at all.  The only thing I get is an ObjectFactory method with this signature:  public JAXBElement<String> createMyEnum(String value)